# Populating cells based on another cell range's value

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I have a cell range c5:cc5 that has values ranging from 0-23 (time). I would like for a corresponding row (15) to populate if the number is either 11 or 23. Sorry for such a noob question, I just am very new to VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub Populate()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("C5:CC5")
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If v = 11 Or v = 23 Then
            r.Offset(10, 0).Value = "Populate"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need VBA for this?

You may add the following formula to your second range ($C$15 - $CC$15):

=IF(OR(C5=11,C5=23),C5,"")